# How to save a student from the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, one is called Employer and the other is called Student. Employers can view student profiles. How can I let employers save student profiles they like?

What I mean by that is, when the employer views a student profile and they like it, they must be able to click "save" and a link to that user profile will be saved and displayed on the employers profile. So when the employer goes to his own profile page, there will be a section called "Saved students" and links to the profiles of the students will be there.

I was thinking I add an array called "saved_profiles" to the employer model and then add a "save" button to the student profile. When an employer clicks it, the web address they are looking at right now, gets added to the saved_profiles array. By web address, I mean like `"www.mywebsite.com/students/jake-madison"`. I'm not completely sure how to implement this though, any help on how to make this happen will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

An array on the "employers" table is what we would call a "denormalized" strategy. A "normalized" strategy would involve storing that save as a record in a join table. The denormalized solution is quick and easy - at first. It can cause headaches later on. So let's talk about the normalized solution using Rail's magical [has many through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association.

**rails**

```
class Employer
  has_many :employer_students
  has_many :students, through: :employer_students

class Student

class EmployerStudent
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :employer
```

**database**

```
table: students
columns: id, name

table: employers
columns: id, name

table: employer_students
columns: employer_id, student_id
```

When an employer "saves" a student's profile, we create a record in the employer_students table, linking that employer to that student. Then, when we want to see the students that an employer has saved, we do a join.

```
employer.students
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! What kind of headaches are we talking about when we use a denormalized strategy?

Comment: The denormalized strategy is essentially caching the result. Caching a result like this makes updates trickier (imagine deleting a "save") as well as queries (e.g. return all employers who have saved students with an id in this array). Both of these operations become more error prone and much, much slower at scale because you cannot leverage the decades of database optimizations - you basically have to do it in application memory instead of in the db.

Comment: Got it. So I already have two models with id's. One is the student model and the other is the employer model. So I have to make another model called employer_student with employer_id and student_id? Then what should I do? I understand your answer is explaining what I have to do, would you please be able to update it so it explains how I do it? Thanks a lot

Comment: @LizzyTheLearner I'm a little hesitant to spoon feed that here. How about this: I've linked to the relevant Rails docs, which tell you all that and more. Learning to find answers in the official docs is a great long-term survival skill. If you're still struggling after trying to follow those docs, ping me again and I'll try to address what you're still struggling with?